# Overwriting a string by concatenating another string

Tags: php

There are hundreds of places in my project which contain the following code:

```
include $root . $template;
```

Where `$root` is document root for the relevant part of the CRM and `$template` is the HTML template file. The `$root` variable is different for different parts of the CRM.

I want to now make all parts of the CRM use the same template file. I can't simply change `$root` to the central document root because there are other places in the code which use that variable. I just want to change it for loading the template.

Is there a way to save time, so I don't have to go over all the places in my code where this appears? Is there perhaps a way of making the `$template` string overwrite the `$root` string when concatinated?

i.e.

```
$root="$_SERVER['document_root']."\some_folder";
$template="[something_to_ignore_concatination?]".$_SERVER['document_root']."\template_file";
//So $root.$template = just $template
```

Comment: First use an constant for `$root` it will not change, so dosomething  like `define('APPROOT','/foo/bar')`. Then make this `$template = APPROOT."/rest/of/the/path"`

Comment: Why not just do a global find and replace in your text editor? find `include $root . $template;` and replace with `include $template;`. Sublime text 3 definitely has this ability for example

Comment: Are you asking hypothetically if this is possible, or would you actually use such a solution?

Comment: If you are using framework like MVC  or other where all request are rewrite to some `index.php` or some other file and from there execution begin, there you can override variable

Comment: @Spholt There's many different files with this, I would have to do that on hundreds of files (my last resort)

Comment: `$str_one = '';
$str_two = 'two';
$str = ($str_one != '') ? $str_one.$str_two : $str_two;
echo $str;
$str_one = 'one';
$str = ($str_one != '') ? $str_one.$str_two : $str_two;
echo $str;`

Comment: @AlinPurcaru I would use the fastest solution

Comment: @dlofrodloh are you looking to be selective then? i got the impression you wanted them all replaced? A text editor will replace all in one go!

Comment: @dlofrodloh Then do a search and replace with your IDE or some command line tool.

Comment: Perhaps that is the best solution

Comment: Purely as a theoretical exercise, I think what you are asking may be possible with some creative include paths and symlinks, but I strongly suggest to just go for the replace solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning: What you'll see below is an abomination, do not use this in real software!**

Assuming these values:

```
$_SERVER['document_root'] = 'path/to/root'

$root == $_SERVER['document_root'] . '/some_folder' == 'path/to/root/some_folder'

$template == '/' . $_SERVER['document_root'] . '/file.php' == '/path/to/root/file.php'

$root . $template == 'path/to/root/some_folder/path/to/root/file.php'
```

You could symlink

```
path/to/root/some_folder/path/to/root -> path/to/root/
```

So that the double path still gets resolved.

Note: The paths above should be treated as relative to one of the folders added to the PHP include_path.

Comment: Very creative, thanks for the solution. You're right though, I should probably search&replace as best practice.